# req.headers['x-access-token'] is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am trying to use token authentication using `axios` by sending `x-access-token` header and I get `null` as the header value when checking it in my server.

FRONT:

```
  fetchUser = () => {

    let data = {
      username: this.state.username
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url:'https://server.com/getuser',
      data: { 
        username: this.state.username
      },
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-access-token',
        'x-access-token': this.state.apiToken
      }
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.user)
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('was problem adding credit in server')
      })
  }
```

SERVER:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
    console.log('this is req.headers', token)
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, message: 'No token provided.' });

    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('error with token')
        conaole.log('decoded token',decoded)
        return res.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
        }
        UserData.findOneAndUpdate(
            {username: req.body.username}
            (err, user) => { 
                if(err) {
                    console.log('error ,' , err) 
                    res.send(err);
                } else {

                    res.send(user);

                }
            }
        );
    })  
})
```

Comment: If you are using any proxy server header won't be carried.

Comment: so I should just send the token in the body?

Comment: Not necessary. If the server is behind proxy server you must add header forwarding in proxy server.other wise it shoudl work fine.try req.get('header name')